# How to sync my fork and merge before sending pull request

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I just started working with a pull and fork model. I keep sync my fork and create a new branch when I have to fix something or for a new feature.

I'd like to know what to do when I have to face the following situation:

Let's suppose that I start creating a new feature

[image]

When I finish my new feature and before creating a pull request with this new branch, I find that my fork is 1 commit behind  master, so I sync my fork and I get this:

[image]

Now my question is what I should do before sending the pull request? I think I should merge C4 into F2 but not sure if this is the correct approach or I should use rebase instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I prefer merging, other people prefer rebasing.

At https://www.atlassian.com/git/articles/git-team-workflows-merge-or-rebase
the author states

> My empirical pulse on all-things-git – scientific, I know! – is that the always merge approach has a slightly bigger mind share. But the always rebase field is also pretty vocal online.

If done right it doesn't really matter if you merge or rebase.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you don't have to sync your branch by merging master or rebasing onto master, since you stated that you finished the pull request. If merging your feature back to the master branch would create a conflict, then you may want to synchronize first (merge or rebase) to resolve the conflict, so that the upstream doesn't have to deal with it.

In case your pull request was not finished yet, you would merge master into feature (or rebase onto master) if you depend on the changes in master. Don't synchronize just for the sake of synchronizing.